# relationship between slug and get absolute url, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, django

I'm very confused right now, if some one can clarify this I would highly appreciate the help.
so I have models.py like this

```
class Post(models.Model):

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("post", args={"slug": self.slug})
```

and

```
    url(r'^post/(?P<slug>[\w|\-]+)/$', views.post, name='post'),
```

so get_absolute_url needs to direct domain/post/slug.name but It's not doing this....does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: I think that you need to use `kwargs`. Like this: `reverse("post", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})`

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ddsnowboard commented:

It is either:

```
reverse("post", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
```

or

```
reverse("post", args=[self.slug])
```

`kwargs` expects a dictionary, `args` expects an array:

Start of the method definition in django/core/urlresolvers.py:

```
def reverse(viewname, urlconf=None, args=None, kwargs=None, prefix=None, current_app=None):
    if urlconf is None:
        urlconf = get_urlconf()
    resolver = get_resolver(urlconf)
    args = args or []
    kwargs = kwargs or {}
```